# How to get specific data from API request without creating data classes including other data classes?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

for example:
{
"error": false,
"message": "",
"code": "",
"ver": "v1.0.0",
"base": "https://,,,,,,,,,.com/",
"count": 1,
"updated": "2020-10-28T19:40:51+03:00",
"data": [
{
"id": "44",
"slug": "human-resources",
"name": "Human resources",
"img1": null,
"img2": "page_44/1560347480_2.jpg",
"date": "2019-05-31",
"des": "'vvvvvv.v",
"sendMail": "info@....",
"iframe_url": "ff/ff"
}
]
}

this is api json response.
I want only "data": [] value, not the rest.
Is there a way I can avoid creating data class for whole api response instead just request "data": [..] value?

I am using Android Studio Kotlin Retrofit Moshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to extract data from that JSON string. You can do that with:

```
JSONArray dataArray;
try {
    dataArray = new JSONObject(yourString).optJSONArray("data");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // whatever
}
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); ++i) {
    // do whatever you want with each object:
    String name = dataArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("name");
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. the JSON response above in postman result, I mean in coding: interface ApiService {

    @GET("/EN/humanResource")
    fun getHumanResource():
            Call<HumanResource>
}                                                                                                                                                        what can I add here or at the and of the    /EN/humanResource so it will only call data:... values not the rest?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. If the server sends you the whole string, you have to extract the part that you need, or otherwise you have to change the server code.